# Not getting any error in this program but my required output is not coming. Could someone help me?

Tags: java, methods, constructor

```
class ThisIsASubClass {
    private int count=0;
    public ThisIsASubClass(){
    }
    public ThisIsASubClass(int num){
        count=num;
    }
    public int disp(){
        return count;
    }
}
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ThisIsASubClass obj=new ThisIsASubClass();
        ThisIsASubClass obj1=new ThisIsASubClass(12);
        System.out.print(obj.disp());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the output as 0, but my required output is 12. I tried this using methods it works fine but using constructor I'm not sure what point I'm missing.

Comment: System.out.print(obj1.disp()); will give you 12

Comment: @user3768428 : Here in using default constructor, You are not passing any value so method will return default value of `count` that is 0..!!

Comment: Why did you think it would be 12?

Comment: You have **two** object instances.  obj1.disp() will return 12, while obj.disp() will return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of `count` if `0`.

**Then look at your default constructor.**

```
public ThisIsASubClass(){
    //there is nothing inside 
}
```

`count=0;` after calling the default constructor. if you call the method `disp()` after the default constructor, it print returns zero;

**Now look at the `ThisIsASubClass(int num)` constructor.**

`count=num;` after calling this constructor.if you call the method `disp()` after this constructor, it returns `num`;

**After that look at objects you have created.**

```
    ThisIsASubClass obj=new ThisIsASubClass();
    ThisIsASubClass obj1=new ThisIsASubClass(12);
```

**Now you should understand that `obj.disp() = 0` and `obj1.disp() = 12`**

Answer (score 0):

Each instance (object) you create via `new ThisIsASubClass` gets its own `count` field. You're initializing that field to `0`. You have two constructors: One that doesn't take any arguments and doesn't change `count`, and one that takes an `int` argument and *does* change `count`.

In your `main`, you have two *separate* calls to your constructors, first to the one that takes no arguments and leaves `count` alone:

```
ThisIsASubClass obj=new ThisIsASubClass();
```

...and then a second, separate one to the constructor that does take an argument and set `count`:

```
ThisIsASubClass obj1=new ThisIsASubClass(12);
```

There is no interaction between the two separate instances (objects) you've created. So you end up with an instance referenced by `obj` that has `count` equal to `0`, and a separate instance referenced by `obj1` that has `count` equal to `12`:

```
            +-----------+
obj-------->| count: 0  |
            +-----------+

            +-----------+
obj1------->| count: 12 |
            +-----------+
```

Then this line uses the instance referenced by `obj`:

```
System.out.print(obj.disp());
```

...and so it outputs `0`, because `obj`'s `count` is `0`. If you did

```
System.out.print(obj1.disp());
// Difference ------^
```

...you'd get `12` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you create instances of class, each instance will have their own instance variables. Those variable will NOT be shared across instances.
In this case you are setting the value of count as 12 in `obj1` but you are printing the value of count of `obj` which is not initialized through constructor . So it will print 0.